# ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches error while unit testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, jruby, ruby-test

I found a lot of questions with same title but could not found the appropriate answer.

I am testing a controller

**Player Controller**

```
def create
 player = Player.create(params[':player'])

if player.valid?
  # if creation successful, log the player in:
  player_session = PlayerSession.create(
    player: player,
    session_token: ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  )

  render json: {session_token: player_session.session_token}
else
  render json: {error: "Player name already exists."}, status: :unprocessable_entity
 end
end
```

**Player Controller Test**

```
test "create" do
    post(:create,
            {
                'player' => {
                    'player_name' => "usman", 
                    'password' => 123, 
                    'email' => 'ranasaani@gmail.com'
                }
            }
        )
    assert_select response.body
end
```

while executing the test file the following **errors display on console**.

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:player=>{"player_name"=>"usman", "password"=>123, "email"=>"ranasaani@gmail.com"}, :controller=>"pl
ayers", :action=>"create"}
    D:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:424:in `raise_routing_error'
    D:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:406:in `generate'
    D:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:453:in `generate'
    D:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:449:in `generate_extras'
    D:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:445:in `extra_keys'
    D:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:143:in `assign_parameters'
    D:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:402:in `process'
    D:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:47:in `process'
    D:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:355:in `post'
    D:/Projects/lyricle/test/functional/players_controller_test.rb:5:in `test_create'
    org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1659:in `__send__'
```

why this error is here?

Comment: Can you provide the related route configuration from your `config/routes.rb` ?

Comment: your controller is defined in a wrong way !

Comment: Just the following code is there 
`App::Application.routes.draw do

end'

Comment: Just add line `resources :players`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [define routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) if you want anything to be able to access your controller.

So, in your `config/routes.rb` :

```
App::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :your_resource_plural_name
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The create action should be like this:

```
def create
 @player = Player.new(params[:player])
 #your code
end
```

also you need to add new action before create action:

```
 def new
    @player = Player.new
end
```

in routes.rb you should have `resources :players`

`@player` is an instance variable to make you able to call it in the view also.

See [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) to create your first application.

Also check [Rails for Zombies](http://railsforzombies.org/) they are very good